# ASP.NET DetailsView Update doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, detailsview

I use all data BoundField in DetailsView from SQL Server. I get the correct display, then I click Edit, then edit some dropdownlist with SQLDataSource and some textboxes. Then I click Update, nothing happen, still same old value and no error. Anyone know why it doesn't work? Here my code,

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="DatabaseName,ServerName,Instance" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
        <Fields>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DatabaseName" HeaderText="DatabaseName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DatabaseName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServerName" SortExpression="ServerName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServerName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkProcess" SortExpression="WorkProcess">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="workprocess" DataTextField="WorkProcess" DataValueField="WorkProcess">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="workprocess" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkProcess] FROM [tblWorkProcess]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" DataSourceID="workprocess" DataTextField="WorkProcess" DataValueField="WorkProcess">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="workprocess" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkProcess] FROM [tblWorkProcess]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WorkProcess") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Primary_DBA" SortExpression="Primary_DBA">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="userid" DataTextField="UserID" DataValueField="UserID">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserID] FROM [tblDBA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server" DataSourceID="userid" DataTextField="UserID" DataValueField="UserID">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserID] FROM [tblDBA]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Primary_DBA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TMLASGroupNumber" SortExpression="TMLASGroupNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMLAS" DataTextField="TMLASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMLASGroupNumber">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMLAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMLASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_LAS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMLAS" DataTextField="TMLASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMLASGroupNumber">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMLAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMLASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_LAS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TMLASGroupNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TMASGroupNumber" SortExpression="TMASGroupNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMAS" DataTextField="TMASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMASGroupNumber">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList11" runat="server" DataSourceID="TMAS" DataTextField="TMASGroupNumber" DataValueField="TMASGroupNumber">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TMAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TMASGroupNumber] FROM [tblTM_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TMASGroupNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IIASGroupNumber" SortExpression="IIASGroupNumber">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="IIAS" DataTextField="IIASGroupNumber" DataValueField="IIASGroupNumber">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="IIAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [IIASGroupNumber] FROM [tblII_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList12" runat="server" DataSourceID="IIAS" DataTextField="IIASGroupNumber" DataValueField="IIASGroupNumber">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="IIAS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [IIASGroupNumber] FROM [tblII_AS]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IIASGroupNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Architecture" SortExpression="Architecture">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN NEA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNConnect.com</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNDMZ.COM</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow NEA</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList13" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSN NEA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNConnect.com</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>BSNDMZ.COM</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow EAP</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Dow NEA</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Architecture") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Version" SortExpression="Version">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008 R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2012</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2008 R2 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2012 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList14" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Oracle 11g R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2008 R2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Server 2012</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2008 R2 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>SQL Svr 2012 SS%S</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Version") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quarter_Close_Vital" HeaderText="Quarter_Close_Vital" SortExpression="Quarter_Close_Vital" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Business_Importance" HeaderText="Business_Importance" SortExpression="Business_Importance" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Application_Number" HeaderText="Application_Number" SortExpression="Application_Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Role_Based_Security_Doc" HeaderText="Role_Based_Security_Doc" SortExpression="Role_Based_Security_Doc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Max_Users" HeaderText="Max_Users" SortExpression="Max_Users" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Storage_Requirements" HeaderText="Storage_Requirements" SortExpression="Storage_Requirements" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Projected_Growth" HeaderText="Projected_Growth" SortExpression="Projected_Growth" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data_Owner_1" HeaderText="Data_Owner_1" SortExpression="Data_Owner_1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data_Owner_2" HeaderText="Data_Owner_2" SortExpression="Data_Owner_2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="SID" SortExpression="SID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Alias" HeaderText="Alias" SortExpression="Alias" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Instance" HeaderText="Instance" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Instance" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Backup_Nodes" HeaderText="Backup_Nodes" SortExpression="Backup_Nodes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Portfolio_Lookup" HeaderText="Portfolio_Lookup" SortExpression="Portfolio_Lookup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ConnectionString" HeaderText="ConnectionString" SortExpression="ConnectionString" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="InstanceOccurence" HeaderText="InstanceOccurence" SortExpression="InstanceOccurence" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OccurenceNormalState" HeaderText="OccurenceNormalState" SortExpression="OccurenceNormalState" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SupportedFuntionalArea" HeaderText="SupportedFuntionalArea" SortExpression="SupportedFuntionalArea" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblDatabase] WHERE [DatabaseName] = @original_DatabaseName AND [ServerName] = @original_ServerName AND [Instance] = @original_Instance AND [WorkProcess] = @original_WorkProcess AND [Primary_DBA] = @original_Primary_DBA AND [TMLASGroupNumber] = @original_TMLASGroupNumber AND [TMASGroupNumber] = @original_TMASGroupNumber AND [IIASGroupNumber] = @original_IIASGroupNumber AND (([Architecture] = @original_Architecture) OR ([Architecture] IS NULL AND @original_Architecture IS NULL)) AND (([Version] = @original_Version) OR ([Version] IS NULL AND @original_Version IS NULL)) AND (([Quarter_Close_Vital] = @original_Quarter_Close_Vital) OR ([Quarter_Close_Vital] IS NULL AND @original_Quarter_Close_Vital IS NULL)) AND (([Business_Importance] = @original_Business_Importance) OR ([Business_Importance] IS NULL AND @original_Business_Importance IS NULL)) AND (([Application_Number] = @original_Application_Number) OR ([Application_Number] IS NULL AND @original_Application_Number IS NULL)) AND (([Description] = @original_Description) OR ([Description] IS NULL AND @original_Description IS NULL)) AND (([Role_Based_Security_Doc] = @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc) OR ([Role_Based_Security_Doc] IS NULL AND @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc IS NULL)) AND (([Max_Users] = @original_Max_Users) OR ([Max_Users] IS NULL AND @original_Max_Users IS NULL)) AND (([Storage_Requirements] = @original_Storage_Requirements) OR ([Storage_Requirements] IS NULL AND @original_Storage_Requirements IS NULL)) AND (([Projected_Growth] = @original_Projected_Growth) OR ([Projected_Growth] IS NULL AND @original_Projected_Growth IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_1] = @original_Data_Owner_1) OR ([Data_Owner_1] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_1 IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_2] = @original_Data_Owner_2) OR ([Data_Owner_2] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_2 IS NULL)) AND (([SID] = @original_SID) OR ([SID] IS NULL AND @original_SID IS NULL)) AND (([Alias] = @original_Alias) OR ([Alias] IS NULL AND @original_Alias IS NULL)) AND (([Backup_Nodes] = @original_Backup_Nodes) OR ([Backup_Nodes] IS NULL AND @original_Backup_Nodes IS NULL)) AND (([Portfolio_Lookup] = @original_Portfolio_Lookup) OR ([Portfolio_Lookup] IS NULL AND @original_Portfolio_Lookup IS NULL)) AND (([Notes] = @original_Notes) OR ([Notes] IS NULL AND @original_Notes IS NULL)) AND (([ConnectionString] = @original_ConnectionString) OR ([ConnectionString] IS NULL AND @original_ConnectionString IS NULL)) AND (([InstanceOccurence] = @original_InstanceOccurence) OR ([InstanceOccurence] IS NULL AND @original_InstanceOccurence IS NULL)) AND (([OccurenceNormalState] = @original_OccurenceNormalState) OR ([OccurenceNormalState] IS NULL AND @original_OccurenceNormalState IS NULL)) AND (([SupportedFuntionalArea] = @original_SupportedFuntionalArea) OR ([SupportedFuntionalArea] IS NULL AND @original_SupportedFuntionalArea IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblDatabase] ([DatabaseName], [ServerName], [WorkProcess], [Primary_DBA], [TMLASGroupNumber], [TMASGroupNumber], [IIASGroupNumber], [Architecture], [Version], [Quarter_Close_Vital], [Business_Importance], [Application_Number], [Description], [Role_Based_Security_Doc], [Max_Users], [Storage_Requirements], [Projected_Growth], [Data_Owner_1], [Data_Owner_2], [SID], [Alias], [Instance], [Backup_Nodes], [Portfolio_Lookup], [Notes], [ConnectionString], [InstanceOccurence], [OccurenceNormalState], [SupportedFuntionalArea]) VALUES (@DatabaseName, @ServerName, @WorkProcess, @Primary_DBA, @TMLASGroupNumber, @TMASGroupNumber, @IIASGroupNumber, @Architecture, @Version, @Quarter_Close_Vital, @Business_Importance, @Application_Number, @Description, @Role_Based_Security_Doc, @Max_Users, @Storage_Requirements, @Projected_Growth, @Data_Owner_1, @Data_Owner_2, @SID, @Alias, @Instance, @Backup_Nodes, @Portfolio_Lookup, @Notes, @ConnectionString, @InstanceOccurence, @OccurenceNormalState, @SupportedFuntionalArea)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblDatabase]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblDatabase] SET [WorkProcess] = @WorkProcess, [Primary_DBA] = @Primary_DBA, [TMLASGroupNumber] = @TMLASGroupNumber, [TMASGroupNumber] = @TMASGroupNumber, [IIASGroupNumber] = @IIASGroupNumber, [Architecture] = @Architecture, [Version] = @Version, [Quarter_Close_Vital] = @Quarter_Close_Vital, [Business_Importance] = @Business_Importance, [Application_Number] = @Application_Number, [Description] = @Description, [Role_Based_Security_Doc] = @Role_Based_Security_Doc, [Max_Users] = @Max_Users, [Storage_Requirements] = @Storage_Requirements, [Projected_Growth] = @Projected_Growth, [Data_Owner_1] = @Data_Owner_1, [Data_Owner_2] = @Data_Owner_2, [SID] = @SID, [Alias] = @Alias, [Backup_Nodes] = @Backup_Nodes, [Portfolio_Lookup] = @Portfolio_Lookup, [Notes] = @Notes, [ConnectionString] = @ConnectionString, [InstanceOccurence] = @InstanceOccurence, [OccurenceNormalState] = @OccurenceNormalState, [SupportedFuntionalArea] = @SupportedFuntionalArea WHERE [DatabaseName] = @original_DatabaseName AND [ServerName] = @original_ServerName AND [Instance] = @original_Instance AND [WorkProcess] = @original_WorkProcess AND [Primary_DBA] = @original_Primary_DBA AND [TMLASGroupNumber] = @original_TMLASGroupNumber AND [TMASGroupNumber] = @original_TMASGroupNumber AND [IIASGroupNumber] = @original_IIASGroupNumber AND (([Architecture] = @original_Architecture) OR ([Architecture] IS NULL AND @original_Architecture IS NULL)) AND (([Version] = @original_Version) OR ([Version] IS NULL AND @original_Version IS NULL)) AND (([Quarter_Close_Vital] = @original_Quarter_Close_Vital) OR ([Quarter_Close_Vital] IS NULL AND @original_Quarter_Close_Vital IS NULL)) AND (([Business_Importance] = @original_Business_Importance) OR ([Business_Importance] IS NULL AND @original_Business_Importance IS NULL)) AND (([Application_Number] = @original_Application_Number) OR ([Application_Number] IS NULL AND @original_Application_Number IS NULL)) AND (([Description] = @original_Description) OR ([Description] IS NULL AND @original_Description IS NULL)) AND (([Role_Based_Security_Doc] = @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc) OR ([Role_Based_Security_Doc] IS NULL AND @original_Role_Based_Security_Doc IS NULL)) AND (([Max_Users] = @original_Max_Users) OR ([Max_Users] IS NULL AND @original_Max_Users IS NULL)) AND (([Storage_Requirements] = @original_Storage_Requirements) OR ([Storage_Requirements] IS NULL AND @original_Storage_Requirements IS NULL)) AND (([Projected_Growth] = @original_Projected_Growth) OR ([Projected_Growth] IS NULL AND @original_Projected_Growth IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_1] = @original_Data_Owner_1) OR ([Data_Owner_1] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_1 IS NULL)) AND (([Data_Owner_2] = @original_Data_Owner_2) OR ([Data_Owner_2] IS NULL AND @original_Data_Owner_2 IS NULL)) AND (([SID] = @original_SID) OR ([SID] IS NULL AND @original_SID IS NULL)) AND (([Alias] = @original_Alias) OR ([Alias] IS NULL AND @original_Alias IS NULL)) AND (([Backup_Nodes] = @original_Backup_Nodes) OR ([Backup_Nodes] IS NULL AND @original_Backup_Nodes IS NULL)) AND (([Portfolio_Lookup] = @original_Portfolio_Lookup) OR ([Portfolio_Lookup] IS NULL AND @original_Portfolio_Lookup IS NULL)) AND (([Notes] = @original_Notes) OR ([Notes] IS NULL AND @original_Notes IS NULL)) AND (([ConnectionString] = @original_ConnectionString) OR ([ConnectionString] IS NULL AND @original_ConnectionString IS NULL)) AND (([InstanceOccurence] = @original_InstanceOccurence) OR ([InstanceOccurence] IS NULL AND @original_InstanceOccurence IS NULL)) AND (([OccurenceNormalState] = @original_OccurenceNormalState) OR ([OccurenceNormalState] IS NULL AND @original_OccurenceNormalState IS NULL)) AND (([SupportedFuntionalArea] = @original_SupportedFuntionalArea) OR ([SupportedFuntionalArea] IS NULL AND @original_SupportedFuntionalArea IS NULL))">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_DatabaseName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ServerName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Instance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkProcess" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Primary_DBA" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TMLASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TMASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_IIASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Architecture" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Version" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Quarter_Close_Vital" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Business_Importance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Application_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Role_Based_Security_Doc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Max_Users" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Storage_Requirements" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Projected_Growth" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Data_Owner_1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Data_Owner_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_SID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Alias" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Backup_Nodes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Portfolio_Lookup" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ConnectionString" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_InstanceOccurence" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OccurenceNormalState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_SupportedFuntionalArea" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="WorkProcess" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Primary_DBA" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TMLASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="TMASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="IIASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Architecture" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Version" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Quarter_Close_Vital" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Business_Importance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Application_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Role_Based_Security_Doc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Max_Users" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Storage_Requirements" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Projected_Growth" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Data_Owner_1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Data_Owner_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Alias" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Backup_Nodes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Portfolio_Lookup" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ConnectionString" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="InstanceOccurence" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OccurenceNormalState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SupportedFuntionalArea" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_DatabaseName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ServerName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Instance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_WorkProcess" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Primary_DBA" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TMLASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_TMASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_IIASGroupNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Architecture" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Version" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Quarter_Close_Vital" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Business_Importance" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Application_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Role_Based_Security_Doc" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Max_Users" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Storage_Requirements" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Projected_Growth" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Data_Owner_1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Data_Owner_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_SID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Alias" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Backup_Nodes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Portfolio_Lookup" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ConnectionString" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_InstanceOccurence" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_OccurenceNormalState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_SupportedFuntionalArea" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but there is no error statement. It just nothing happen at all. I add some dropbox with sqldatasource in edit template.

Comment: I see you have textboxes too. When you change the value in the textboxes does it work correctly? You also have quite a few DropDownLists - do they all have the same problem?

Comment: I did change value in textboxes. Still nothing happen and no error except insert part where it say cannot insert null value which I already did by select value from dropdownlist. I don't get it why because I select the editing option, same for insert and delete. It should automatic enable edit to work. All I do is change some input like replace textbox to Dropdownlist in EditTemplate.

Comment: I found it strange when I start over to default without dropdownlist or any change in edititemtemplate. It work fine and it did change. I don't know why it won't response when I change something in edititemtemplate.

Comment: I found out why it doesn't work. When I replace textbox to dropdownlist. It wipe the databinding. I have to go to Edit DataBinding to set it target to specific column. Before, it left it blank that is why it not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it doesn't work.
When I replace textbox to dropdownlist, It wipes the `databinding`. I have to go to Edit DataBinding to set it target to specific column.
Before, it left it blank that is why it does not change anything.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, You wrote a detailed explanation so consider accepting it an an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question while searching for a solution for the same issue. The fix for me was to set the `DataKeyNames` property of the DetailsView to the primary key for the table.